# Multiple slide down on click reveal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have multiple objects with same class and hidden div's. On click of each span object I want to reveal div next to it and close any other div that is opened.

While I was able to achieve that, there is a problem, where I can't close same div object once it's opened. It just jumps up and down again. I tried with toggle, but it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.open').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.gameData').slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).next('.gameData').slideDown('fast');
  });
});
```

```css
.gameData {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="open">open1</span>
<div class="gameData">this is content1</div>
<br>
<span class="open">open2</span>
<div class="gameData">this is content2</div>
<br>
<span class="open">open3</span>
<div class="gameData">this is content3</div>
<br>
```

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/teva/0sm2zk4q/2/

Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0sm2zk4q/3/ something like this?

Comment: You can do in this way https://jsfiddle.net/anil56samal/egpwgcdx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `slideUp` all except the current dialog (using the `not()` function) and then `slideToggle` the current one.

See demo below:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.open').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.gameData').not(jQuery(this).next('.gameData')).slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).next('.gameData').slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

```css
.gameData {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="open">open1</span>
<div class="gameData">this is content1</div>
<br>
<span class="open">open2</span>
<div class="gameData">this is content2</div>
<br>
<span class="open">open3</span>
<div class="gameData">this is content3</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are triggering `jQuery(this).next('.gameData').slideDown('fast');`  Everytime you clcik on open

Edit your code like this:

```
    jQuery('.open').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.gameData').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).next('.gameData').slideToggle('fast');}
```